# Generate an array of fields from a spark data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe with 6 columns, which produces output like below

```
c1 | c2 |  c3  |  c4  |  c5  | c6                                                                            
 1 |  2 |   3  |   4  |   5  |  6                                                   
 2 |  3 |   4  |  5   |  5   |  7
```

I need to convert this as JSON file with the last 3 columns as a single array which look like below

```
{"c1":"1","c2":"2","c3" :"3",array["c4":"4","c5":"5","c6":"6"]}     
{"c1":"2","c2":"3","c3" :"4",array["c4":"5","c5":"6","c6":"7"]}
```

I know we can convert a dataframe to an JSON file by calling `df.toJson`. Can somebody help me how to generate an array with the last 3 fields.

Comment: can share your solution which was working/not working and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Your output is not a valid json. What would be the key for the array value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your output is not a valid JSON. I'm assuming the output you want is something like:

```
{
    "c1": "2",
    "c2": "3",
    "c3": "4",
    "remaining": {
        "c4": "5",
        "c5": "6",
        "c6": "7"
    }
}
```

In this case, you can do it with the following code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val result = df.select($"c1", $"c2", $"c3", struct("c4", "c5", "c6").as("remaining")).toJSON
```

If you actually want an array, but with no keys, like:

```
{
    "c1": "2",
    "c2": "3",
    "c3": "4",
    "array": ["5", "6", "7"]
}
```

Then you can try with the following code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val result = df.select($"c1", $"c2", $"c3", array("c4", "c5", "c6").as("array")).toJSON
```